# inheritance hierarchy and generics

Tags: protobuf-net

I have the following hierarchy -

```
ProtoBase

 SomeType :ProtoBase

 TypeCacheData<T> : ProtoBase

 ListCacheData<T> : TypedCacheData<List<T>>
```

and am using a

```
ListCacheData<SomeType>
```

in the code -

I wasn't sure what inheritance attributes should be included at the latest release to accomplish this -

TypeCacheData has a property called Value of, which is of type T.

I've tried a few things but got the "ProtoBase" can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy..

What's the uptodate recommended way to accomplish this ?

I saw this -
[ProtoBuf-Net ProtoInclude Generic Type Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408133/protobuf-net-protoinclude-generic-type-subclass?rq=1)

but it's pretty old...

Thanks !

UPDATE - 
I eventually came up with the following - which seems to work -

Does it follow the lines of the recommended way to go  , or is my solution overly complex or perhaps even wrong ?

Thanks !!

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(2, typeof(LiteAnswer))]
    [ProtoInclude(5, typeof(TypeCacheData<List<int>>))]
    [ProtoInclude(6, typeof(TypeCacheData<List<short>>))]
    [ProtoInclude(7, typeof(TypeCacheData<List<LiteAnswer>>))]
    public class ProtoBase
    {


    }

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(ListCacheData<LiteAnswer>))]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(ListCacheData<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(102, typeof(ListCacheData<short>))]
public class TypeCacheData<T> : ProtoBase { 
   // omitting class implementation to keep example concise

}


   [ProtoContract]
    public class ListCacheData<T> : TypeCacheData<List<T>>
```

When using the above I'm able to deserialize/ deserialize properly isntances of the following -

```
ListCacheData<int> 
ListCacheData<short>
ListCacheData<LiteAnswer>
```

Comment: Any chance to get an update for this soon ?  It's really important as I'm planning to install this in production code soon :)