# Binding a ProtoInclude to the corresponding RuntimeTypeModel binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm currently trying out protobuf-net, and have got problem with serialization of the following class structure:

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class WorkerResponseBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public WorkerErrorMessage ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public bool IsError { get; set; }

    protected WorkerResponseBase()
    {
    }

    protected WorkerResponseBase(bool isSuccess, [CanBeNull] string errorMessage)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        IsError = !isSuccess;
        ErrorMessage = new WorkerErrorMessage(errorMessage);
    }
}

[ProtoContract()]
public class WorkerResponse<TPayload> : WorkerResponseBase
{
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public TPayload PayloadOrNull { get; private set; }

    ....
}
```

When I first tried it with a concrete class as in e.g. `WorkerResponse<LoginResult>`, I was only able to have PayloadOrNull serialized.

Alright, I got to google a bit on how to make this work. I found this answer: [ProtoBuf-Net ProtoInclude Generic Type Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408133/protobuf-net-protoinclude-generic-type-subclass?rq=1)

People mentioned, that `[ProtoInclude]` is required.

So, for testing this, I was trying to decorate the `WorkerResponseBase` with `[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(WorkerResponse<LoginResult>))]`. Bingo, serialization works perfectly.

Now, as you might be able to imagine, this is a very generic container for a response, so I wouldn't want to have to define all possible TPayloads in the base class, so a bit further down in the linked comment I found, that I should also be able to do this dynamically, and eventually via reflection.

So for testing purposes, I did the following instead of the [ProtoInclude]:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(WorkerResponseBase), false)
    .AddSubType(100, typeof(WorkerResponse<LoginResult>));
```

However, when I run this, no serialization works at all, not even the serialization of the `PayloadOrNull`.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `false` in your code (to `Add`) is basically saying "and I'm going to control everything myself, don't process the properties and their attributes - I'll tell you explicitly". Since you're *not* doing that, you probably want to pass `true`. In the pending V3 API, this is an optional parameter that defaults to `true`.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the response. I should have noted in my post, that I also tried this with 'true', but didn't have much success as well.

Comment: @Sossenbinder k, I'll see what I can repro

Comment: @Sossenbinder this seems to work fine; do you have a minimal repro where it *doesn't* behave as expected? https://gist.github.com/mgravell/bbe4b98f627c8b057f8ccab357ec243f

Comment: You know what, this is on me - The call was alright, I just missed to define it on the correct side of the communication.

Comment: I just came across this situation again, and tried it again with the said RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add call (with a proper true flag), however, this time I'm actually getting errors regarding "Cannot create an abstract class". It works fine with the attribute. Any ideas? I did call this on both sides of the involved services.

Comment: @Sossenbinder I'd need to see a minimal repro of the thing that is not working, so that I can actually press "go" and see the same thing you're seeing

Comment: I once again screwed up and rechecked my reflection code which does this logic, only to find out that one side does not bind this properly. Thanks for being patient with my incompetence, I swear this was the last time :P